# After installing a CDK of angular getting an error during compilation

Tags: angular6

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:29:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 29     get enabled(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:30:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 30     set enabled(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:128:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 128     get enabled(): boolean;
>               ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:129:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 129     set enabled(value: boolean);
>               ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:134:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 134     get autoCapture(): boolean;
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts:135:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 135     set autoCapture(value: boolean);
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts:96:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 96     get activeItemIndex(): number | null;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts:98:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 98     get activeItem(): T | null;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts:69:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 69     get politeness(): AriaLivePoliteness;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts:70:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 70     set politeness(value: AriaLivePoliteness);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts:26:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 26     get dir(): Direction;
>              ~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts:27:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 27     set dir(value: Direction);
>              ~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts:29:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 29     get value(): Direction;
>              ~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/collections/selection-model.d.ts:24:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 24     get selected(): T[];
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:62:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 62     get disabled(): any;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:63:9 -
>   39m91merror TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient
>   context.
>
> 63     set disabled(value: any);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:66:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 66     get debounce(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts:67:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 67     set debounce(value: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:60:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 60     get offsetX(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:61:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 61     set offsetX(offsetX: number);
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:63:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 63     get offsetY(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:64:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 64     set offsetY(offsetY: number);
>              ~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:86:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 86     get hasBackdrop(): any;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:87:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 87     set hasBackdrop(value: any);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:89:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 89     get lockPosition(): any;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:90:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 90     set lockPosition(value: any);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:92:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 92     get flexibleDimensions(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:93:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 93     set flexibleDimensions(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:95:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 95     get growAfterOpen(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:96:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 96     set growAfterOpen(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:98:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 98     get push(): boolean;
>              ~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:99:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 99     set push(value: boolean);
>              ~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:112:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 112     get overlayRef(): OverlayRef;
>               ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts:114:9 -
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 114     get dir(): Direction;
>               ~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts:55:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 55     get overlayElement(): HTMLElement;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts:57:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 57     get backdropElement(): HTMLElement | null;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts:63:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 63     get hostElement(): HTMLElement;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts:36:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 36     get _isRtl(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts:40:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 40     get onPositionChange():
>   Observable;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts:43:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 43     get positions(): ConnectionPositionPair[];
>              ~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/flexible-connected-position-strategy.d.ts:91:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 91     get positions(): ConnectionPositionPair[];
>              ~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts:49:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 49     get portal(): Portal | null;
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts:50:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 50     set portal(portal: Portal | null);
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts:54:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 54     get attachedRef(): CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal.d.ts:24:9 - error TS1086: An
>   accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 24     get isAttached(): boolean;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal.d.ts:63:9 - error TS1086: An
>   accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 63     get origin(): ElementRef;
>              ~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:75:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 75     get itemSize(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:76:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 76     set itemSize(value: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:82:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 82     get minBufferPx(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:83:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 83     set minBufferPx(value: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:88:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 88     get maxBufferPx(): number;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts:89:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 89     set maxBufferPx(value: number);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts:49:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 49     get cdkVirtualForOf(): DataSource | Observable |
>   NgIterable | null | undefined;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts:50:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 50     set cdkVirtualForOf(value: DataSource | Observable |
>   NgIterable | null | undefined);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts:56:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 56     get cdkVirtualForTrackBy(): TrackByFunction | undefined;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts:57:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 57     set cdkVirtualForTrackBy(fn: TrackByFunction | undefined);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts:60:9 - error
>   TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 60     set cdkVirtualForTemplate(value:
>   TemplateRef>);
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.d.ts:27:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 27     get orientation(): 'horizontal' | 'vertical';
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~ node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.d.ts:28:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 28     set orientation(orientation: 'horizontal' | 'vertical');
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~

I did npm install and npm update but it's not worked for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is due to the version incompatibility between angular/cdk, angular/material and angular/core. Most specifically, Angular Core version 8.x.x is not compatible with Angular CDK version 9.x.x.

Solution:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. In package.json, change the version of cdk and material. Save.
3. `npm install`.

In my case, I was having:

```
"@angular/cdk": "~9.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/material": "~9.0.0"
```

and I changed this to:

```
"@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/material": "~8.2.3"
```

and deleted node_modules and did `npm install`. Fixed.

Comment: In my case it was not necessary to delete node_modules, i just did `ng serve`

Answer (score 6):

Update Angular Core and CLI to latest version:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

After this you may get issue `ModuleWithProviders not found`, if you have not used generic ModuleWithProviders. The update changes this to generic one but does not imports it.

So, do `import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';`

Hopefully, this will solve the issue.

You might also need to run `ng add @angular/localize` if your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.

Answer (score 1):

The error is for version incompatibility, check the version details for angular, 
angular/material & angular/cdk in package.json file or `ng --version` command on the project.

In my case the version angular version was 8.x and when i installed angular material & cdk dependencies the version was 9.x, i updated the material & cdk version to below versions and it worked fine

```
"@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3"
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3"
```

You can view all the material versions in the material.angular.io website 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ztb.png)

Answer (score 0):

[NCU](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) can fix the issue. Run the following command in the angular directory

```
ncu -u
npm install
```